# How can I prevent "Media Device" from showing up on a network, while keeping my computer on the network? (Windows 10 Home)

Tags: networking, windows-10

How can I prevent my computer from showing up as a media device on a network, while still having it show up as a regular computer? I am running Windows 10 Home x64.

I want this to show up

[image: 2]

But not this

[image: 1]

Comment: Disable sharing.

Comment: Thank you gronostaj for editing my post to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like you could do something like sc delete "WMPNetworkSvc"

check out this thread
[disable-windows-media-player-media-server-network-locations](https://superuser.com/questions/631399/disable-windows-media-player-media-server-network-locations)

It would be wise to make a system restore before hand ;)

Comment: Please quote and cite all relevant information from your link in your answer itself, your answer by itself, should answer the question (it currently does not).  Of course removing a default service is an absolutely horrible idea and also overkill just disable device media sharing.